# App crashing when setting delegate and datasoruce

Tags: delegates, uitableview

If I want to set my delegate and datasource for my uitableview my app crashes. What I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)loadView {
 NSLog(@"AddListViewController");
 ShareListViewController *shareListViewController = [[ShareListViewController alloc] init];

 UITableView *shareListView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 30, 100,     200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

 shareListView.delegate = shareListViewController;
 shareListView.dataSource = shareListViewController;


 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:shareListView];

 [shareListViewController release];
 }
```

And my ShareListViewController

```
@interface ShareListViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

 }

 @end
```

It also not working if I remove the protocols.

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are releasing the `shareListController` controller. This is wrong, since both, that `dataSource`property as well as the `delegate` property of a table view are declared as having retention policy `assign`, which means, that they do *not* `retain` their values. This is the responsibility of client application/view controller.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITableViewDataSource> dataSource
```

See the [UITableView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW68).

The best approach seems to be to declare an ivar in your view controller like:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController {
    ... other stuff ...
    UITableView* shareListView;
    ShareListController* shareListController;
}
... more stuff ...
@end
```

In `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` (or, wherever else you set up the table view) `alloc`/`init` the `shareListController` as usual, but instead of releasing the object after you have set up the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties, you remember the reference (you still own it) in the `shareListController` ivar.

Finally, in the view controller's `dealloc` method, do:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    ... release other stuff ...
    shareListView.delegate = nil;      // Really, really defensive
    shareListView.dataSource = nil;    // here, but it won't hurt
    [shareListView release];
    [shareListController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I thought the simplest way would be to do a simple autorelease. But that don't helps either. What would you recommend?

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry totally not got it! Thanks a lot! Grüsse aus der Schweiz